# Creating forEach loop with swig/twig

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

I am trying to create a loop that will output the values into a table for me. What I have so far doesn't load anywhere on the rendered page. Nothing to show for it. I am not too sure how to do a loop with swig/twig so no idea what to include in this post. Please have a look at the code and if you need something else I will add it at request. My attempt at a loop:

```
{%  for aps in aps  %}
  <tr>
   <td>{{aps.name}}</td>
   <td>{{aps.manufacturer}}</td>
   <td>{{aps.model}}</td>
   <td>{{aps.name}}</td>
   <td>{{aps.notes}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Model:

```
var accessPointsSchema = new Schema({
  name: {String},
  manufacturer: {type: String},
  model: {type: String},
  IPAdress: {type: String},
  MACAdress: {type: String},
  range: {type: Number()},
  bands: {type: String},
  channel: {type: Number},
  dateBought: {type: Date},
  PoE: {type: Boolean},
  assetNumber: {type: Number},
  warrantyExpiration: {type: Date},
  location: {type: String},
  notes: {type: String},
  author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
      },
      email: String
   }
});
```

Route:

```
// show model
  app.get('/dashboard/it/model',
    setRender('dashboard/it/model'),
    setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    dashboard.getDefault,
    (req, res) => {
      console.log("Reached end/start thing");
      AP.find({}, function(err, allAP){
        console.log(allAP);
       if(err){
         console.log("Reached if");
           console.log(err);
       } else {
         console.log("Reached else");
          setRender('dashboard/it/model',{aps:allAP});
       }
    });
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you've called the data `ap` in `{ap:allAP}` but then you're attempting to loop over something called `aps` in `for ap in aps`.

Comment: @skirtle really don't know how the for loop works with swig. I know twig docs are supposed to be close to swig (almost the same) so I used them and got confused about half way down this page

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

I saw the for user in users and tried to model mine after that.

Comment: Try changing it to `{aps: allAP}` so that the data matches the template.

Comment: Also, I don't know what `setRender` does exactly but it seems unlikely that you should be calling it twice like that.

Comment: @skirtle Nope no change. I update the OP to reflect the changes I made

Comment: @skirtle I am calling it twice because I don't know how else to pass the data through to the template. Maybe that is the issue? I can't remove the first call of it without errors due to the user template I am using.

Comment: Quite possibly, but I can't tell from what you've posted. Perhaps try passing suitable fake data to the first call to `setRender` to see if that works? You also seem to have changed the loop variable from `ap` to `aps` in your edit. Change it back, it was right before. If you use `for ap in aps` then you need `aps` in the data and you can access properties of the items using `ap` inside the loop. It's a bit like `aps.forEach(function(ap) {...})`.

Comment: @skirtle  I tried the fake data `{aps: "Test data"}` with no luck, I hope that is what you meant for me to try.

Comment: The key word was **suitable** fake data. If it doesn't look like real data (i.e. an array of objects with the right properties) then how can the loop be expected to work? You should post the code for `setRender`, I'm currently just guessing that it behaves like `res.render`.

Comment: @skirtle I did that test data then did `{{aps}}` up above in another place outside the loop to see if the data was even being passed through and it is not. 

As for the real data showing up, I can `console.log(allAP);` right before and after the place I try to insert it and it works so the `find()`  is working right. The route is not passing the data through seems to be the issue, I thought it was the loop but not sure it is even that anymore.

Comment: @skirtle This is the github repo for the `setRender`, it does act like `res.render` which I know I could get to work if I could remove that `setRender` but I can't I have tried many times and gotten help on here and reddit both saying it won't work

https://github.com/eddywashere/middleware-responder

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt an answer based on the code you posted at https://github.com/joshk132/asset-management

Firstly, `setRender` doesn't seem to take a second argument. So instead try using something like this:

```
app.get('/dashboard/it/model',
    setRender('dashboard/it/model'),
    setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    (req, res, next) => { // Moved this before getDefault
        console.log("Reached end/start thing");
        AP.find({}, function(err, allAP) {
            console.log(allAP);
            if(err){
                console.log("Reached if");
                console.log(err);
                next(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Reached else");
                res.locals.aps = allAP; // Set the data in locals
                next();
            }
        });
    },
    dashboard.getDefault
);
```

Importantly I've moved the database stuff before the call to `dashboard.getDefault` as `getDefault` calls `res.render` and the data all needs to be loaded before that happens.

You'll also need to address the `next()` call at the end of `getDefault` as there's nothing else to do.

The template would then be something like this:

```
{%  for ap in aps  %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ap.name}}</td>
```

and so on.

Comment: For addressing the `next()` call at the end of `getDefault` could I just do a `(req, res) {console.log("Something here")}`

Comment: I commented out the `next()` call and it hangs when I try and load it. I tested this just on a `GET /model/new` as a quick and easy to reverse test. I should add that your code does fix my OP issue. I will try to resolve the `GET /models/new issue`

Comment: It hangs for me with the route `// create model
  app.get('/dashboard/it/model/new',
    setRender('dashboard/it/modelCreate'),
    setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    (req, res, next) => {
      console.log("I worked");
next();
    },
    dashboard.getDefault);`

Comment: Does it log out the message `I worked`? Put some logging in `getDefault` to see whether it gets that far. If it does, use the logging to figure out exactly what it does in there.

Comment: I got it to work idk what I did though so will figure that out so I know for next time